How do I find the correct name in a column with thousands of entries?
I am currently learning SQL for data analysis. In today's exercise, I had to answer these questions:
*In 2015, how many people were of the official age for secondary education broken down by region of the world?
For this query, you will need to perform some additional tasks before returning the result:

Exclude rows with a missing region.
Use the SUM(value) to calculate the total population for a given grain size.
Sort by highest population region first.*

And now to my problem: How do I find the correct name in a column with thousands of entries? To answer the question “how many people were of the official age for secondary education”
This text “Population of the official age for secondary education, both sexes (number)” was given to us. But how would I find it out if it wasn't given?
Hier ist der Code den ich geschrieben hatte:
SELECT
  summary.region,
  SUM(edu.value) AS secondary_edu_population
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education` AS edu
INNER JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.country_summary` AS summary
ON edu.country_code = summary.country_code
  WHERE
    summary.region IS NOT NULL
  -- here is the problem--  AND edu.indicator_name = 'Population of the official age for secondary education, both sexes (number)' 
    AND edu.year = 2015
    GROUP BY summary.region
    ORDER BY secondary_edu_population DESC


Not sure what are you asking . you must know what the official age for secondary education means

This row was given: 'Population of the official age for secondary education, both sexes (number)'
My question is, how would I find this name myself in a column with 1000 entries if it was not given?

It sounds like your table has columns like:
Region  Year Indicator  Value
If you needed to just get the names of all of the indicators so you could find the one you needed, then
select distinct indicator
from yourtable

would do it. If you have a clue as to what the indicator name might be, then you could narrow it down:
select distinct indictaor
from yourtable
where indicator like '%education%'

